# simple java web service java

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to java web service. while writing sample web service using jax-rs am getting following error in stack trace.  run a server  which load a page as http status 404. I need to write simple web service for my understanding and then i have to access web service via restful client in android application. am here post my entire web service please help me.

pls lead me in right way. thanks in advance

```
Aug 26, 2014 6:55:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
 INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;.
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:04 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
                WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:webService' did not find a matching property.
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:04 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
                INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:04 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
                INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
                INFO: Initialization processed in 699 ms
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
                INFO: Starting service Catalina
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
                INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:06 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
                INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
                  webService
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:06 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
                INFO: Root resource classes found:
                  class webService.myserviceClass
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:06 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
                INFO: No provider classes found.
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:06 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
                INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 03:28 PM'
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
                INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
                INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
                Aug 26, 2014 6:55:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
                INFO: Server startup in 2082 ms
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name>webService</display-name>


       <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>webService</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**myserviceClass.java**

```
package webService;


    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    // Plain old Java Object it does not extend as class or implements 
    // an interface

    // The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
    // Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
    // text, XML and HTML. 

    // The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

    //Sets the path to base URL + /hello
    @Path("/hello")
    public class myserviceClass {

      // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
      }

      // This method is called if XML is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
      }

      // This method is called if HTML is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
      }

    }
```

Comment: There are no errors in logs, add your web.xml file, your web-service code and what URL you are trying to access in your post.

Comment: i post my code pls help me

Comment: What URL you are trying to access?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/webService/WEB-INF/classes/webService/myserviceClass.java

Comment: Try this url with your server up: localhost:8080/contextOfYourApplication/rest/hello - Since you have mapped in your web.xml to call the jersey servlet in /rest, and you mapped the path /hello in your class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you have to access is of the format:

```
http://your_hostname:port-number/application-context-name/rest/path-name-of-your-web-service
```

`<hostname>` is `localhost` as the application is running on your machine

`<port-number>` is `8080` - default port for tomcat server

`<application-context-name>` is name of your application deployed in tomcat server, if you have named it as `webService` then application context name will be `webService`

`rest` -- this is the name of the jersey Servlet configured in your web.xml file, as per your xml it is `rest`

`<path-name-of-your-web-service>` -- this will be `/hello` as per your java web-service code.

So try with:

```
http://localhost:8080/webService/rest/hello
```

Comment: i have one more question , i need to host my  web service  how can it be possible to  access from another pc as a client.

Comment: If the machines are in same network, then you can access the same URL except that you need to change `localhost` to your `hostname` or `IP address`

Comment: i did , but i got "can't load webpage message"

Comment: yeah sure i will do it.  i need ur help pls provide ur g+

Comment: sorry for that, you can always use SO or any queries, you will definitely get better help from experts.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any error in your tomcat log. Bu I think there is no servlet for your web service which handle the request. (control web.xml) Or you are trying to access wrong context.

You can look this https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html  tutorial.